# why is this libreoffice Edit control event handler not working

Tags: events, controls, libreoffice, calc, uno

I need to create this dialog programatically because it will have a variable number of controls depending on the client. (The naming conventions are sloppy right now because i am in the middle adapting someone else's code.) The code chokes when the focusGained sub is entered (see below).

I have tried many things but especially of note is: if i change the relevant lines to deal with the textChanged event instead, it all works as expected.

```
Sub main

    Dim dlgmodel As Variant
    Dim oComponents As Variant
    Dim oDoc As Variant

    dlgmodel = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.awt.UnoControlDialogModel")
    With dlgmodel
        .Name = "checkwriter"
        .Title = "check writer"
        .PositionX = 170
        .PositionY = 70
        .Width = 190
        .Height = 100
        .DesktopAsParent = false ' or true, does not affect problem
    End With

    Dim oModel As Variant

    oModel = dlgmodel.createInstance("com.sun.star.awt.UnoControlGroupBoxModel")
    omodel.name = "rbgroup"
    dlgmodel.insertByName(oModel.Name, oModel)

    dim j%

    for j = 0 to 3         ' 3 is for example
        oModel = dlgmodel.createInstance("com.sun.star.awt.UnoControlRadioButtonModel")
        With oModel
            .Name = "rb" & j
            .PositionX = 10
            .PositionY = 6 + j * 15
            .Width = 12
            .Height = 12
            .groupname = "rbgroup"
        End With
        dlgmodel.insertByName(oModel.Name, oModel)

        oModel = dlgmodel.createInstance("com.sun.star.awt.UnoControlEditModel")
        with omodel
            .Name = "txt" & j
            .PositionX = 40
            .PositionY = 6 + j * 15
            .Width = 40
            .Height = 12
        end with
        dlgmodel.insertByName(oModel.Name, oModel)
    next

    Dim oDlg As Variant
    oDlg = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.awt.UnoControlDialog")
    oDlg.setModel(dlgmodel)


    Dim oControl As Variant
    oListener = CreateUnoListener("txt_", "com.sun.star.awt.XFocusListener")

    oControl = oDlg.getControl("txt0")           ' testing one single edit control
    ocontrol.addFocusListener(oListener)

    Dim oWindow As Variant
    oWindow = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.awt.Toolkit")

    oDlg.createPeer(oWindow, null)

    oDlg.execute()
End Sub

'entering focusGained() causes
' "BASIC runtime error. Property or method not found: $(ARG1)."
' after clearing that, the print statement executes.
' ***warning*** without the print statement the dialog will become uncloseable.

sub txt_focusGained(event as object)
    print "txt1" 
end sub
```

Comment: Pretty good initial question, with all code and information necessary to reproduce the problem. However, it could be made better by removing irrelevant parts of the code such as the radio buttons. Also, the title is too long, and that question should be at the end instead.

Answer (score 0):

The interface [com.sun.star.awt.XFocusListener](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/awt/XFocusListener.html) requires two methods. You only implemented one of them, which is why the error occurs.

To fix it, add the following:

```
sub txt_focusLost(event as object)
    print "txt2" 
end sub
```

However, are you sure you want a focus listener? As you will see by running it, the revised code results in an infinite loop. Focus is generally tricky and works differently depending on the operating system. Normally I use `textChanged` instead.

Comment: lack of focusLost() was definitely the main part of the problem

Answer (score 0):

details of solution with example here

https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/218979/why-is-this-edit-control-event-handler-not-working/